# server error not displaying in browser

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mysql

I have purchased new cloud server and installed appache-php-mysql. And then I hosted one of my website in it. All it works fine. But some pages was displayed partially. I couldn't found any errors through browser. Finally I checked the apache2 error log files. The issue was because I was not installed bcmath library. My question is that why didn't this error shown in browser? how to configure my server to visible all errors through the browser. Or let me know any other best way. Because I am a php developer and a beginner in Linux. I test the progress of my works through browser.

And also I got a mysql error as, when I run a query that return more than 14000 rows. In browser I couldn't found any errors shown. and the page was blank. I spend hours useless. I was tested the application in my local server, It was worked fine. but in server it is not. Finally I tried for hours and checked mysql configuration. The problem was When I run this query, the mysql is restarting automatically. So how can solve these.

Comment: Did you turn on [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?

Comment: If there is a syntax error, suppose `$i` is an undefined variable, then `echo $i;` is showing error. But the bcmath error not displaying in browser.